# Disable Google API key without access to google account

Tags: google, credit-card, api

I was trying the new google api - I created anonymous account - added there my debit card, set up the API key for google maps. Tried API and pushed my API key to shared repository (yes I know - my fault). Then I forgot my credentials to the google account - as it was just only trial.

Now I want to either:

**1/ remove my debit card from google** - but cannot remember the password so I cannot sign into cloud.console

OR

**2/ disable the API key** - because it is in shared repository.

Any help? I am scared that someone will find the API key, will use it and I will be charged on my debit card. I blocked online charges in internet banking - but still - there is my name on the card so Google can charge me - I am scared I will have some big debt somewhere and I will not know about it until bill collector comes... :(

Comment: If it's any consolation, it would take a very long time to brute force an API key. Have you tried the "forgot password" option?

Comment: Yes I tried the "forgot pasword" option, but to no success. The problem is that the API key is already compromised - any one in the company have access to shared repository and if someone will find it and  will start using -  it it will generate debt to Google in my name.

Comment: If all else fails you can always cancel the card before somebody abuses it.

Comment: I see. I'm afraid I won't be much help then - my only two recommendations would be to reach out to Google support, and to disable the card in the meantime.